# Case Records not returned in Classic or Console Search - Returned in Query Editor

Tags: soql, search, indexing

I create a case, it is case number 123456789.

If I search for case number 123456789, it is not returned Salesforce Classic search, this includes clicking search all.  It is also not returned in the advanced search. In the console top search bar, the case is not returned when I search for the case number either.

However, related objects for the case are returned. We have a custom object we relate to our cases and that object does appear in the search results, but the case itself does not at this point.

When I run a query for the case number, the case and Id are returned. When I URL hack and paste in the Id, the case displays. Once I have viewed the case, it is returned in all of the searches above. It is even returned for other users who were having trouble seeing the case as well.

The field is set to indexed.

The case does display in the the case views and in reports, but does not display in the default search results.

Sounds like a SF internal indexing issue, but they are still looking into the issue.

Any thoughts or similar experiences?

Comment: Are you searching from a profile that has access to all data? Any triggers that may affect ownership/access to the case?

Comment: Yes, I am searching from the system administrator profile. It does not display when I initially search through the default search methods, but after I URL hack to get to the case, the case then displays in the searches for myself and for all other users.

Comment: What type of field is case number? Asking because case number is idiomatically an auto-number field and not user-specified.

Comment: 123456789 was just an example. It is the default case number field.

Comment: Is the Case tab hidden for your profile?

Comment: No the case view is not hidden from my profile or from any of the other users profiles experiencing this issue.

Comment: There can be a delay between when a record is created and when it appears in the search results. I'm sure you've already thought of this but your question doesn't indicate it and noone else has commented on it. How long are you waiting between when the record is created and when attempting to search? According to documentation this can take up to 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of this issue was summarized by Salesforce as the following:

> The indexing thread for your instance's node encountered an error and
>   was stopped.

Salesforce restarted the indexing service and case objects are now being properly indexed and are now searchable.

Answer (score 2):

The search engine lags behind record creation/edits by some time. It's typically somewhere less than 30 seconds or so, but it can be several minutes or even hours if the search engine is having a problem or is suspended (which they may do for maintenance or to diagnose a problem). However, the search engine also has a local cache of records a user has looked at; if the terms appear in this local cache, it'll be returned for that user even though other users can't search for it yet. Once the system is caught up, all users with access to the record will be able to search for it.

Comment: This is what I thought, and I have experienced a similar issue with Knowledge articles in the past, but I appreciate the confirmation.

Comment: @S.B. That's certainly unusual. They might have a search engine problem.